# Is this an appropriate use of sirrah

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Hortensio:
>
> ‘Sirrah! I will not bear these braves of thine’

In this context, Hortensio is arguing with Lucentio and called him *sirrah*. Those two characters are actually rich people disguised as teachers.

> A term of address used to inferiors or children to express impatience,
>   contempt, etc.

[Sirrah definition by Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sirrah)

To my understanding, since both of them are teachers, sirrah is not appropriate to use in this context because Lucentio isn't actually inferior to Hortensio, rather they are of the same rank. Am i correct?

Comment: It's Shakespeare.  He can use words any way he wants.

Comment: The point is that it *is* inappropriate. It's like calling your co-worker an *asshole* or saying *damn it!* in an argument with a priest today: you would do it specifically because of its inappropriateness.

Answer (score 1):

The term '[Sirrah](http://www.finedictionary.com/sirrah.html)'  is used to show contempt, so it is appropriate to the context:

> - A term of address implying inferiority and used in anger, contempt, reproach, or disrespectful familiarity, addressed to a man or boy, but sometimes to a woman. In sililoquies often preceded by ah. Not used in the plural.

(www.finedictionary.com)

- For the usage of "sirrah" in Shakespeare's works you can refer to this [extract](https://books.google.it/books?id=_Yc6AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA323&lpg=PA323&dq=sirrah%20usage&source=bl&ots=47bMk3FhX4&sig=oL-BjB-0F_FGKjuDHJxcctgVHbY&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CEQQ6AEwCWoVChMIwv7g_-zDxwIVRS4aCh00mArd#v=onepage&q=sirrah%20usage&f=false).